# How to check if user is a b2b user?

Tags: magento2, b2b

In my file

> app/design/frontend/Eadesignro/a1turbo/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

I have to test if user is logged and if he is a b2b user. 
I test if user is logged with these lines of code:

```
$_loggedin = $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCart()->getCustomerSession()->isLoggedIn();
if( $_loggedin )
    echo 'LOGGED';
    else echo 'NOT LOGGED';
```

But how can I check if the user is a b2b user? thank you!

Comment: B2B is customer group here ?

Comment: yes,B2B is customer group

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you need any help there then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below line in your phtml to get customer's group ID

```
<?php $customerGroupId = $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCart()->getCustomerSession()->getCustomerGroupId(); ?>
```

You can check B2B customer's group ID in backend and you can add condition based on that ID.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome Buddy 